# Saving data from bs4 and request in a usable manner

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I am too new to python, so please forgive me for stupid questions. Thanks in advance.

I have the following data(float) printed out with bs4 and requests, with the code (print link.find_all("id"), link.text)

- X a
- X b
- X c
- Y a
- Y b
- Y c
- Z a
- Z b
- Z c

Instead, I would like to save it like:

- X a b c
- Y a b c
- Z a b c

and then save it into a text file so that I can use it afterwards. (I don't even know how to save some data into a file with python)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python, here's a quick example of creating a *dict* of *list*s and writing it to a text file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import collections

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie2</a>;
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
anchors = soup.find_all('a')
data = {}  # collections.OrderedDict() if order matters

for item in anchors:
    key = item.get('id')
    if key not in data.keys():
        data.update({key: [item.text]})
    else:
        values = data[key]
        values.append(item.text)
        data.update({key: values})

with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in data.items():
        line = key + ' ' + ' '.join(value) + '\n'
        f.write(line)

# example.txt
# link1 Elsie
# link3 Tillie Tillie2
# link2 Lacie
```